# Trouble creating a simple SPA with Angular JS $route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, single-page-application, ng-view

I have the following HTML snippet inside my `index.html` page:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

The scope of my main module should be the entire pages as I have this:

```
<html ng-app="spa">
```

I have included `angular.min.js` and `angular.min.route.js` in the `<head>`

All of my JS is included like this:

```
<!--JavaScript Sources-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular-route.js"></script>
<!--End JavaScript Source-->
<!--JavaScript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/js/view.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/js/controllers.js"></script>
<!--End JavaScript-->
```

The `spa` module is defined like this:

```
var spa = angular.module("spa", ['ngRoute']);

spa.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when(
    "/home", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/home.html",
    }).when(
    "/about", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/about.html",
    }).when(
    "/skills", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/skills.html",
    }).when(
    "/experience", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/experience.html",
    }).when(
    "/resume", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/resume.html",
    }).when(
    "/contact", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/contact.html",
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "#/home";
    });
}]);
```

`partials` is a directors in the same folder as `index.html` as is the `js` directory. I've just finished the CodeSchool Angular JS series, and most of my short career has been spent in PHP. CodeSchool didn't mention `routes` so I'm unsure if this is correct, or why it's not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I also had an included JS file which hadn't been created as well as defining controllers in tags which had not been defined yet. I.E. `controllers.js` and `mainController`.

Comment: can you be a bit more descriptive than "not working"?  and where is the `<ng-view>` in your HTML?

Comment: Regardless of route nothing is displayed instead of the `<div`. I know for a fact that `home.html` contains content, I have gone to the directory in the browser.

Comment: I don't think that `redirectTo` will work with the `#`.

Comment: are there any errors in the console? does the network request tab in the console show any requests for the template pages?

Comment: does navigating to `http://example.com/#/home` return your expected result?

Comment: @Claies, no this doesn't work either.

Comment: are you ***sure*** that you aren't getting any errors in the console?

Comment: ok, so there ***are*** errors in the console, as you have indicated in the comments on the attempted answer.  And based on the errors, it doesn't have anything at all to do with the code you have posted in the question.

Comment: I've downvoted the question, not only because the accepted answer isn't really the solution (the solution was provided in comments), but the code in the question isn't even representative of the problem.  It will not be easy for others in the future to understand if this problem is similar to their issue, or even what *really* solved it.

Comment: well I'm glad you were able to get things sorted; hopefully you recognize now where the actual errors you should be looking for are at so you can debug these problems easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **changing**:

```
var spa = angular.module("spa", ['ngRoute']);

spa.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when(
    "/home", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/home.html",
    }).when(
    "/about", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/about.html",
    }).when(
    "/skills", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/skills.html",
    }).when(
    "/experience", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/experience.html",
    }).when(
    "/resume", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/resume.html",
    }).when(
    "/contact", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/contact.html",
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "#/home";
    });
}]);
```

**To:**

```
var spa = angular.module('spa', ['ngRoute']);

spa.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/about.html'
            })
            .when('/skills', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/skills.html'
            })
            .when('/experience', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/experience.html'
            })
            .when('/resume', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/resume.html'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/contact.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });
});
```

**Update:**

I just found out that one of the reasons that your application didn't working as expected is that you didn't **include** the **controllers.js** that has **mainController** in your project which is **defined** in your **html**.

**Note:**

Do not end an **object** with **semi-colon**.

**E.g.**

```
{redirectTo: "#/home";}
```

**Change it to**

```
{redirectTo: "/home"}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What's the output in your console? Is there an error?

Comment: Try to place your scripts in the body element.

Comment: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/ng/areq?p0=mainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:6:417
    at Sb (http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:19:510)
    at La (http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:20:78)
    at $get (http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:75:465)

Comment: at http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:57:178
    at q (http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:7:428)
    at M (http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:57:45)
    at g (http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:51:409)
    at g (http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js:51:426)

Comment: I just visited your site. There are many errors in the console. It seems that the **controllers.js** is not present. Try to include it. Also the **mainController** is not present because your **controllers.js** is missing.

Comment: That was it. I didn't realize that I could not specify things that were empty without messing things up. Angular, I suppose, is not as forgiving as HTML in that respect.

Comment: Yup, that's right. Also, do not end an object with **semi-colon**. E.g. {redirectTo: "#/home";} change it to {redirectTo: "/home"}. If you will end it with **semi-colon** it will throw an errror.

Comment: @Claies had a valid complaint and down voted my question. If you could add the answer we found in the comments, I'll re-accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Alberto I.N.J. discovered the answer to my question, and commented.

I didn't realize that I could not specify things that were empty without messing things up. Angular, I suppose, is not as forgiving as HTML in that respect.

What I didn't mention in my question is that one of the JS files I had included, `controllers.js` was empty. As I mentioned before, because I had controllers defined in tags that were not actually there, I threw an error.